unable to scrape data from the web page using Selenium
I'm working on a web scraping script that uses Selenium and BeautifulSoup to automate a BLAST search on the IS Finder website and download the results. The script performs the following tasks:

Initialize Web Browser: Opens a Chrome browser instance using Selenium WebDriver.
Navigate to IS Finder Website: Opens the IS Finder website and navigates to the "TOOLS" and then "Blast" section.
Upload File: Interacts with the web page to upload a specific FASTA file.
Set Parameters: Inputs a job title and sets the e-value parameter for the BLAST search.
Submit Job: Submits the BLAST job and waits for the results page to load.
Save Results: Downloads and saves the resulting HTML page content to a local directory named after the job title.
Extract Query Lines: Parses the saved HTML page to extract "Query" lines and associated links.
Download Linked Pages: Visits each extracted link, downloads the linked page content, and saves it with filenames corresponding to their query lines and other attributes.
Create Directory: Ensures the results are saved in a structured manner within a directory named after the job title.
Close Browser: Properly closes the browser session once all tasks are completed.

Here is my code:
# Necessary webdrivers need to be imported
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import time

# This is for Chrome. Similarly if

# Firefox is needed, then it has to be specified
webBrowser = webdriver.Chrome()

# This will open Is finder site in chrome
webBrowser.get('https://www-is.biotoul.fr/index.php')

# Find and click on the 'TOOLS' link
tools_link = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'TOOLS')))
tools_link.click()

# Find and click on the 'Blast' link
blast_link = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Blast')))
blast_link.click()

# Locate and interact with form elements
file_input = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")))
file_input.send_keys("/Users/somil/Desktop/gene_bank.file/TA373.fasta")


# Enter job title
job_title_input = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input")))
job_title_input.send_keys("TA373")

# Get the job title entered
job_title = job_title_input.get_attribute('value')

# Locate the Evalue input field within the Algorithm parameters fieldset

evalue_input = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='expect']")))

# Clear the current value (if any) and input your custom value
evalue_input.clear()

#set input values
evalue_input.send_keys("0.01")


#submit the task
submit_button = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(( By.CLASS_NAME,"boutonblast")))
submit_button.click()

# Wait until the page is fully loaded
WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*")))
time.sleep(100) ##############ADJUST_TIME_ACCORDING_TO_NEED#######################################################

# Create a directory based on job title
directory_name = f'{job_title}.IS_finder_results'
os.makedirs(directory_name, exist_ok=True)

# Once the content is fully loaded, download the page
page_content = webBrowser.page_source

# Save the page content to a file within the directory
file_name = f'blast_results_{job_title}.html'
file_path = os.path.join(directory_name, file_name)
with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(page_content)
###################################################PART_1_COMPLETE################################################################################

###############PART_2###############################

# Find all elements containing "Query" sections
query_sections = webBrowser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//b[starts-with(text(), "Query=")]')

# Find the "Query" section
query_section = webBrowser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//b[starts-with(text(), "Query=")]')

# Find the first <a> element on the page
continue_link = webBrowser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

# Find all elements with the href attribute
elements_with_href = webBrowser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@href]")

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')

# Find all text elements
text_elements = soup.find_all(text=True)

# Initialize a list to store all occurrences of "Query="
queries = []

# Find all <pre> and <div> elements
query_elements = soup.find_all(['pre', 'div'])

# Iterate over each element
for element in query_elements:
    # Extract text of the element and split into lines
    lines = element.text.split('\n')


    # Filter lines containing "Query="
    query_lines = [line.strip().split(' Genus')[0].replace('Query=', '') for line in lines if 'Query=' in line]

    # Print the query lines
    for line in query_lines:
        print("Query Line:", line)

# Print all extracted queries
for query in queries:
    print("Query Line:", query)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Iterate over all elements with the href attribute
for elem in elements_with_href:
    try:
        # Get the href attribute value
        href = elem.get_attribute("href")

        # Exclude links leading to NCBI and links starting with # and containing #BL_ORD_ID
        if "ncbi" not in href and not href.startswith("#") and "#BL_ORD_ID" not in href:
            print("Link:", href)

            # Download the page content using BeautifulSoup
            response = requests.get(href, verify=False)  # bypass SSL certificate verification
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

            # Extract query identifier from href
            IS_class= ""
            if "name=" in href:
                IS_class = href.split("name=")[-1]

            # Save the page content to a file
            filename = f'{job_title}_{query_lines}_{IS_class}.html'  # Extract filename from the URL
            file_path = os.path.join(directory_name, filename)
            with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write(soup.prettify())  # Write prettified HTML content to file
                print(f"Downloaded {filename} successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occurred:", e)

Here is my problem:

Extracting and Storing Query Lines: I need to extract "Query" lines from the HTML content and store them in a way that I can iterate over them later when downloading the linked pages.

Naming Files Correctly: When downloading linked pages, I want to name the files using the corresponding "Query" line and some other attributes from the link. However, I'm having trouble correctly associating each link with its respective "Query" line.


Here is the FASTA file example for TA373.fasta:
    >NODE_195
ACGCACTAATGACATGAATCGCTCCCTTGCGGCGACTCTTGTCATAAGAATGCCGGAGTGTTTTTCCATCAATTGCGATGACGTCTTTATCATCTGAAGTATGGCAATCTCGCATCCAGTTAATAAAGCACTCGTGAAATTTTGCAGGACTGAT
>NODE_97
GGCTGCGGCGCTGCATTTTCTCCCGTTCGCCGTTCTCTGTTTCGATGCGGATGAGTGGCGTGAAGCTTCCCGGCTCGTATACCGTCTGGATACGTGTGGTGTCAGTCTGCACCGTCGTCAGCCTGTCGCCGTCCCACCCGTACCATGTCTCCTCCGGTTTACGCGACAGCGACATCCACCCCGTCAGGTCACGCTCCCGCCGCCATACCCGTTTCGCCATTCGCCGTCCCAGCGGGTCGTAAAGGTAGCGGCTCTCGACCAGTGGCTCGCCATGCTGTATCCGCGTATAGAACACCAGGCGGTGCTGGCTGTCGTAGTGGTAGTGGTGGGTCCGCTCGTCGTCCGTCCGTATCACACCCGCCGGGATGCGGTCCGTCTTCTCCGTCAGTCTGCCGTATTCATCATAGTGGTAAACATAGTGCGCATCCTTCGCGATGCGGTTATCCGGCCACGCCGTGAGTGTACTGTCCGGGTGCAGCTCCGGGTCCGGCGTGACGCGGTTTGCCAGCCCCTGCTCGTTGTATGCGTGTTTCGTCTCATGCTGCCACAGCAGTTCCCCCGTCTCCGGGTTCTCCACCGTCTGGCGTTCGCCGGTCAGGCGGCCTTTATCGTCATAGCCATAGTGGACGGCAACACGGTGGCCTTCACTGGTATGGCTGAGGGTGGTTAACCACCCGTGCTCATCATACTGCCACTGCTCTGCCGGGTCGCCGTTCACCGTCCGGTGCGTGATGCGCTCTGCTTCATCGTAGTACCACTGCGTGACCTGCCCCTCATCCTCGCTGCGGATGAGCTGCCCTGTGGCGCTGTACCGGTAACGCTGTGTCCTGCCATCAAAGCCGCGCTGCTCTGTCAGGCGGTCCAGCACATCGTAGGTAAATTCACTCCGGCTGCCGTTCTCGTTGGTCAGCACGGTGATGCGCCCGGCAGCGTCATACCCCATGCTGCGCGTCAGCCCGCCTTCCGTCACACTCACCGGACGCCCGCGTTTATCATATGCGATGGTGCTGCGTTTACCGTCCGGTGATATCGTTGCTGTCAGGTCGCCTGCGGCACTGTACTCATAACGGGTTTCACGCCCCTGCGCATCCTTCTGCCCTGTCAGCCTGCCGCGGCTGTCATAGAGACTATAAATACTGAGACCTTCCTCCCGGTGAACGGCGATTTGTTGACCGTACCGGTCATACTCATACCGCGTCATGTACCCCGAGCAGTCCGTAAACGCCTGAAGCTGACCGTACCGGTTTCGCGTTATTCTCCGCGTTACCCCGATTCCGTCTTCCACCGCGCCGGGCAGGCTACTGCGGGGGGAGTCATAAAACCAGCGCGTAATGTTACCGTTGCGCGAGGTCTCTTCTGCCAGTCGGCCCTGACGGTCATATTTCCGGCTGCTGCGTAAACCATCCGGATATGTCACTGAAGTCAGTTGCAACTGGCTGTTATAGCCATACCGCACCGTCCTGCCGTCCGGCAGTATCACTGAAGTCAGCTTTCCAGACGCCATATGCAGCCGGTACACCGTCCGCCGCCCCGCCGCATCCGTCTGCGCCTTCAGCCTCCCCGCCTCATCATACTCGCTGCGGGTGATGCTCCCGTCCGCATGCTCCTTCTTCACCACCCGCTTCAGGCCACCTTCGCCTTCCGTGTACAACACCTCCCGCCGGTTCAGGCTGTCCGTGATGGTCACACGGTCCTGCCCGTACTCAAAGCGGTAGTCCAGTCCCTCCGGGTTGACCTGCTCCGTCACCCGACCGGTATCATCATACCGGTAGCGGCTCTCCGGCCTCCCCGCATAATGGTGCGCCACCCCGCCCCGCGCCAGCCAGAACGACTCACTGCGGCTGTAACTTATCTCGCCGGGAAACAGGGGTTCAAAGTGAATACTCCTGCCGCCACTGTCGTTGAGTATCAGGCCTTCATCGCGTATCTGTAAGCGGATATCGAAGGGGGCTTTCCAGCCGGGACCAAACACCCCCACCGGCGCGGGTGTCCTGGTCCGGTAGCTGCTGTAAGCGCGAGAAAGAATAAACGGCAGCGGGCCGGGCAGCGCAAGGTCCGTCTCGCCCGGCAGCACCTTCGCACCCAGCAGCGGGTTCACCGGGTTAGCATAGGTAATCCCTCCCGGACACACCGAGCAGGCCACTCCCGTCGGCGCACCTATCAGCCCCCCCTGCTGAACCCTGCACAATATCCAGTCCCTTGCGGGTCATGTCACCCTGCCGCGCCGCCGGTTTTCCGCTCATGGTTTATTCCTTTTCTTTTACCTTACATGTCCATACAAATAGTTACCTATACTGTCTTTGAATATTGCCCTACCATTTAAAGCCCACCTATTTCTTGCGACAGAAAAGGGATTTCTTTTTTAATCCAATCTATCATTTCATTTTTTTCAAAACATACGTTAATGCCATTCACACTTCCACATTCACCAAAACCATCAAAATAAATTTCACATTTATTATTTTTATTCGAAACAATGTCAACCCCCCATCTTATATCGTTATTCTCCTCCTTCCTGAAATACTTCACTTGCAATAAATCAATTATCTCACCAGCATAAAAATCGCTAACCCCATTCACCACCACTTTATGTTTGTATATTCTCTTGAGACCTTCCTTGCTAAGCGGGGTTAAGGTGGTAACATATGCTGGAAGATTAATTATTTCTATCGTTTTCACACTATCTATTCCACACAATTCATTCACTCGCCCCATCCCCAATACCGAAGCAGAAAATAGAGACAATAAAACCATCAAATATTTCATCATAAAAAAATCTCACTATTCTGGCGTGCCATTTATTGTTGCCGTCTGCGTTGGTGTATTCACACGATAATACACTCCATTATATGCTGTTCTGGTACACTCACCTAAAGTTTTCGTCGCATGCTGTTCAATTAAAGTGATAACTCTCGCCTCTTCTTTATTTTTATATTGTTCATCCGCACGTCTCACAAGCCCCATATAACCATCCTTATCAATAAGATATAAGTGCGCATGAGCAAACTCATGCCCCAAACCTAATGCAGGTGATTGTGATTTCGATTTTAAATCAGTTGAACAAAATAAAGCCGCCTTACCATTCCAATATATAGTCATTTTATCCGGGTCAAATCTAACGTCGGTTTCATTAATATACTCTATCTTTATGGTTTCTTCAGAGCTTAATAAAAAAACTATAGCTTCTTTCATTCGTGAATCTTGTTTTAAATACTCAACAGCCTGATTAAAATCACTTGGATCACCGTTAACATGGAATTTTAAACCCAAAGAATCTATAAACCGAACAGGGTTTAATGGATATTTATACGGATTCCATTCACCTCTTAGCCCAGGGAAAGATTACGAAAGCCCGCTCCCAGCAAGGACTGACGCCAGATAGTTTCTGTCCATGGCTGCTTTTCGCATCTTACGTCTTAACCCTGCCTTGAATACCTTATCATTCGTCAAAATATTAATAGCGATGTGCCGTATCCCTGAAAATAATTCTGCTGCATTTCCTCTTCTTATTTTGCAGTCGTCTTCATTCATTACCACGTCCAGACGCCAATGCAGCTTATTCTCCACGTGCCAGTGGTTTCGGATTGCTGTGGCGAACTTCTCTGCGGTTAAATCAGCAGAACTGATATAATATCTGACCGTCATTTCTGGCTCTTTCTTTTGTTCTGCTATTATTGACCGAAAGGAGACTGCCACGCATAATTTCTTCAGACCTTTCCATTCAAACGTGAAATCAATAAGTTCATCAGGGACATCGCAAACAATATGAAGATGGATTTCTTCTCTGCCGTGACTCTTTTCACTAATGGCGTAACTGTCATGCTCTGGATTATTTAATTCTTTCAGTGGAAATTTTTCCTCAAAGGCTTTATTAAGCCGCCCCTGATTTCCTTTTACAGCGAATAAATAATCACCGCCCTGTTTTTGTATCTTCTCTGCAATATCTTTCTGGCAACCCATCGCATCAGTTGTGATGATTTTTCCTTTAATATCCAGCATGTTAAGAAGTTCAGGGATAGCTGTAATTTCATTGGATTTCTCATCCGTCCTGATCTGTCCGATGACCAGACTGTGCATTGTTGAGAACGCACTAATGACATGAATCGCTCCCTTGCGGCGACTCTTGTCATAAGGATGCCGGAGTGTTTTTCCATCAATTGCGATGACGTCTTTATCAGCTGAAGAATGGCAGTCACGCATCCAGTTAATAAAGCACTCGTGAAATTTTGCAGGACTGATACAGGATACAACTCTGGCAATGGTATCGTGAACAGGAATACCATTTTCAAAATCACCATATTGCTTCAAAAAATCGAGATGTGTTTCCCCAAAATCCTCTATATCTTCCCAGCATTCTGCACCAGAAATAACGGCACAAATAGTCAACAGTAGAATATCCGACAATTTATGTTCCACTTTCCAGGCTTGTCTGTAATCGGGGATAATAGAAATATGTTCCATCAATTTTTTAAGTTCCATTTTGTTCTCCTTAATTATGTAAGGAGTATTTGATCATGTATACGCAATAAAAAACAGCTTTAGGTAATAAGGAATATCTCAATTTTTAAACATAAAATGCGAATTATTTAGTACAAAAAGTGAACTTCTGATGATCTTTCCCTGCCCATTGGGTTCATTAAGATCAAGAATAATGGGAATATGCTCAAGAAGACTTTGAATGTTCACCAGACGTCCTTTTCTAATATATTTAATTATTTGGCGATTAAATTTTAATCAAATCAACAAGGTAAAACCAAGATTAAAGTTGTGATGATAATCACAACTTTAATGATCTTCCCCTGATTCCTCCAGTCCTTTTATTTGGTTACTCTAATGGTTTTATTAATTGTAAATTTTTAAATGTCATGCTTAATAAGCCATCAGAAAAATAAAGAAAAAATTTATATATCCTTTTGTTTTTT


You've provided WAY too much code and your explanation is confusing. You said you downloaded the page successfully. Are you trying to then scrape the downloaded page or another page or ??? Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

Thank you @JeffC and I am sorry for late response. I have edited the title as well as I have provided the functional code for reproducibility. I have break the functions of my script to suitable titles and my problem for better understanding. I hope this helps if there is any thing needed please feel free to ask and i was able to deal with error message but still unable to solve the problem. I am new to python especially selenium so I may not know the technical terms but you are always welcome to enlighten me.

While your question is now clearer that you've put in the individual steps, we still can't get past Step 3 because we don't have your FASTA file. Can you give us a sequence that we can use or is the FASTA file small/simple where we can recreate it easily? Without it, we can't get past that step to see the rest of the problem.

I still think you've provided way too much code that isn't relevant to the problem. The problem is that once you've downloaded the HTML file(s), you aren't able to extract the "Query" lines. I don't understand what you are referring to as a "Query" line. An example would be helpful since we can't see the downloaded page for ourselves.

Hello @JeffC I have uploaded sample fasta file so that you can run the script. When you will blast the fasta file you will navigate to result page in which you will find elements like Query= NODE_5 this is Query lines also under these lines you will find the table "Sequences producing significant alignments" under which you will find clickable elements. I want to get content of those links with the name for example {Job_title}_NODE_195_IS621. Please remember that these files should be named with job title in my case TA373 and family name IS621 with respect to its Query lines.

@JeffC Part one of the scripts will provide key values to the page and download the result page. Second part of the script should do the intended task where i am getting problem, so I thought you would require the whole code to reproduce and replicate the problem. I hope this will clear the confusion.

I'd just create a dictionary or hashset and use Selenium to get the href attribute and then the text relative to that.  So iterate over links and use a locator relative to each link that'll target the text you want to store.  (not sure I completely understand what you wanted though... but you're using soup for a lot of stuff that Selenium will be better for)

is the use of selenium a requirement? It's easier to do all this without it

@GTK no selenium is not the requirnment.

Since selenium is not required, we can achieve the same results using requests and BeautifulSoup.

Steps:

Upload the .fasta file using a POST request.
Use the link in the response to GET the results page and save it to disk.
Extract a list of every (sequence, sequence_href) pair for each Query_line(Node).
Iterate through each pair in each node, download the html and save it to disk.


Code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests
import os 
import re

def upload_fasta_file(path, title, evalue):
  payload = {
    'title': title,
    'expect': evalue,
    'seq': '',
    'database': 'ISfindernt',
    'prog': 'blastn',
    'blast': 'ok',
    'alignment': '0',
    'wordsize': '11',
    'gapcosts': '5 2'
  }
  
  with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    files = {'seqfile': f.read()}

  upload_url = 'https://www-is.biotoul.fr/blast/ncbiIS.php'
  response = requests.post(upload_url, data=payload, files=files, verify=False)
  return response


def extract_query_urls(html):
    tables = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').select('table')
    result = {}
    for table in tables:
        query_line = re.search(r"\nQuery= (\w+)\n", table.previous_sibling.text).group(1)
        result[query_line] = [(a.text, a['href']) for a in table.select('a[href^="../scripts/ficheIS.php?name="]')]

    return result


def save_to_disk(file_name, directory_name, content):
    os.makedirs(directory_name, exist_ok=True)
    file_path = os.path.join(directory_name, file_name)
    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(content)


def main():
    # disable ssl verification warning
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

    # params
    job_title = 'TA373'
    file_path = 'TA373.fasta'
    evalue = '0.01'

    directory_name = f'{job_title}.IS_finder_results'

    # uploading the fasta file
    upload_response = upload_fasta_file(path=file_path, title=job_title, evalue=evalue)

    # extracting the results page url(relative) from upload response
    href = BeautifulSoup(upload_response.text, 'html.parser').a.get('href')

    # fetching the results page
    results_response = requests.get(urljoin(upload_response.url, href), verify=False)
    
    #save results html to disk
    results_soup = BeautifulSoup(results_response.text, "html.parser")
    save_to_disk(f'blast_results_{job_title}.html', directory_name, results_soup.prettify()) 
    
    # extracting target urls from the results page
    query_urls = extract_query_urls(results_response.text) #

    # iterating through Nodes dict; {'NODE_123': [(IS_class, href), ...], ... }
    for query_line, seq_list in query_urls.items():
        for IS_class, href in seq_list:  
            # urljoin to convert from relative to absolute url
            # "../scripts/ficheIS.php?name=ISEc1" --> "https://www-is.biotoul.fr/scripts/ficheIS.php?name=ISEc1"
            response = requests.get(urljoin(results_response.url, href), verify=False)
            
            pretty_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser").prettify()

            # saving each Sequence page to disk
            file_name = f'{job_title}_{query_line}_{IS_class}.html'
            save_to_disk(file_name, directory_name, pretty_html)

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Notes:

This code does not perform any error checking/handling.
The sequence urls seem to follow the pattern ../scripts/ficheIS.php?name={IS_class}
Different Nodes may contain the same sequences, resulting in duplicate GET/SAVE.
The <a> tags on the saved results page will NOT refer to the local (saved) sequence pages.


Possible improvements:

Adding error handling.
Optimize duplication by renaming sequence files from {job_title}_{query_line}_{IS_class}.html to {IS_class}.html AND/OR caching the results.
Replace the hrefs on the results page with local files. (if that is the desired behavior)

